Connection to postresql db from php
I have a php project in which I use postgresql and XAMPP.
The project itself is very small and it's layout looks like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Электроэнергия</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Система учета электроэнергии</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="consumer-form">
            <h2>Добавить потребителя</h2>
            <form action="add_consumer.php" method="post">
                <label for="name">ФИО / Название:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
                <label for="address">Адрес:</label>
                <input type="text" id="address" name="address" required>
                <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
            </form>
        </section>
        <!-- Другие разделы -->
    </main>
</body>
</html>

And php code looks like this:
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=kirilltop228");

if (!$db) {
    die("Ошибка подключения к базе данных: " . pg_last_error());
}

// Получение данных из формы
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

// Запрос к базе данных для добавления потребителя
$result = pg_query_params($db, "INSERT INTO потребители (ФИО_название, адрес) VALUES ($1, $2)", array($name, $address));

// Проверка успешности запроса
if ($result) {
    echo "Потребитель успешно добавлен.";
} else {
    echo "Ошибка при добавлении потребителя: " . pg_last_error($db);
}

// Закрытие соединения с базой данных
pg_close($db);
?>

I am indeed connected to my DB (i checked it via var_dump()), but when i try to submit my form, it gives me 500 error.
I figured out that my problem is:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

From what I can understand, i don't have the pgsql lib. I tried to install it and edit my php.ini file, but it didn't work for me. What can i do?
p.s. im not sure if that is important, but i use macos

"it didn't work for me" - what does that mean? What exactly did you try? Also, "INSERT INTO потребители (ФИО_название, адрес) VALUES ($1, $2)"looks pretty strange to me - shouldn't you use single quotes for preparing a statement?

@NicoHaase That’s how you use prepared statements, to avoid SQL injection. Works perfectly fine

Did you edit php.ini and uncomment the PostgreSQL sections?

See also this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251859/using-postgresql-with-php-under-windows-xampp

@FrankHeikens using double quotes around the query looked strange to me, in combination with parts starting with a $ - I've never used PostgreSQL directly in a PHP application

@NicoHaase This is not specific to PostgreSQL, the quoting is done during mapping the content to the query. Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, it all works the same. PHP, Java, Golang, it all works the same. You only use single quotes for hardcoded content in your queries, never for prepared statements. And in PHP the function pg_query_params() makes your coding really easy, connection + query + array with content and your done.

"Never for prepared statements" - what's the point in never using single quotes for prepared statements? In MySQL, this does not make any sense, nor any huge differences, as the parameters don't start with a $ - which usually makes a difference when switching from double to single quotes
